# Принцип адресного пространства «код-куча-стек»

Tags: c, windows, архитектура, память, стек

Стала необходимость детально изучить как устроена память в компьютере. Коллега на форуме порекомендовал вот эту статью на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/nixsolutions/blog/277759/), которая даст тот минимум, который необходим **разработчику ПО**.

В разделе **«Адресное пространство»** автор примером на Си демонстрирует что сегменты виртуальной памяти действительно идут по порядку: «код-куча-стек».

Я тоже запустил этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int v = 3;
    printf("Code is at %p \n", (void *)main);
    printf("Heap is at %p \n", malloc(8));
    printf("Stack is at %p \n", (void *)&v);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

и вот что у меня вышло:

> Code is at 001B1299
>   Heap is at 00FF5168
>   Stack is at 00EFF87C

Используя [онлайн-ресурс](http://planetcalc.ru/375/), я перевел эти адреса из шестнадцатеричной системы в десятичную и получил:

> Code is at 001B1299 => **1774233** (1)
>   Heap is at 00FF5168 => **16732520** (3)
>   Stack is at 00EFF87C => **15726716** (2)

Если проранжировать эти значения то получается, что порядок *(см. цифры в скобах)* сегментов выделенной виртуальной памяти для процесса таков: «код-**стек**-куча», а не как показано у автора на иллюстрации

[image: адресное пространство по принципу «код-куча-стек»]

«код-**куча**-стек»

---

### Вопрос

Где я ошибся? Что не допонял?

*Не могу дальше читать статью пока этот кусок не пойму).*

Comment: Вам же написали дальше: **"Но все эти три адреса фальшивые. В физической памяти по адресу 0x7ffe60a1465c вовсе не хранится целочисленная переменная со значением 3. Никогда не забывайте, что все пользовательские программы манипулируют виртуальными адресами, и только на уровне ядра или аппаратных драйверов допускается использование адресов физической памяти."**

Comment: @Harry, да этот момент я усвоил. Меня интересует **порядок**. Тогда выходит, что этот порядок актуален только на **физическом уровне**? И все же должен отметить, что сколько бы раз я не запускал приведенный код на Си, порядок выдаваемых значений для **виртуальных** адресов будет тот же (код-стек-куча). Это тоже меня мучает).

Comment: Понимаете, по большому счету - какая вам разница? Я серьезно! Если вы не пишете суперсистемные вещи типа драйверов - то разбирайтесь с моделью памяти языка. Просто тут все врут... Операционка делает вид, что у программы такое-то адресное пространство, программа - что верит в это :) Просто в разных ОС, не говоря уж в разных архитектурах решения могут быть самые разные. Ну, в DOS еще можно было этим заморачиваться - там был доступ везде и ко всему, а сейчас? Вы даже не знаете, где ваша конкретная память реально - может, в RAM, может, на диске...

Comment: В \*nix (например, Linux) все правильно (хотя сегмент стека для обработчика прерываний (или нового thread) при желании можно разместить и в куче или в области статических данных (сегмент кода)). В др. ОС расположение сегментов в виртуальной памяти может отличаться (как у Вас в винде)

Comment: Порядок вообще не важен, каждая ОС распологает их по-своему. На физическом уровне порядок тоже не задан, так как сегменты будут расположены там, куда указывают сегментные регистры. А в x86-64 от сегментов вообще избавились, там плоская модель памяти. В [мануале](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24592.pdf#page=43) от AMD (глава 2) довольно понятно описана модель памяти в x86.

Comment: самое лучшее описание про память "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory" https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf
оно же на русском http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/hard/memory/memory.html